ApiTestCase file upload support (api-platform v2.7.18)
I'm using the ApiTestCase class (from api-platform) to test my API (in Symfony), but the file upload is not working.
I found this post about it: Api Platform: how to test file upload with ApiTestCase
However this doesn't work at all. The $_FILES variable is completely empty when doing a var dump.
This is my code:
        $pdfFile = self::$kernel->getProjectDir().'/app/data/tests/data/ara/blue_feedback.pdf';
        $endPoint = $this->generateUrl('api-single-pdf-analysis');

        $file = new UploadedFile(
            $pdfFile,
            'blue_feedback.pdf',
            'application/pdf'
        );

        $data = static::createClient()->request('POST', $endPoint,
            [
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data', 'apikey' => $this->apiKey],
                'extra' => [
                    'files' => [
                        'pdffile' => $file,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        );

I have double checked the test file and it exists, the API key is also correct. The response is the error code "no file uploaded". I have tried several variations of this code with no luck.
So I'm looking for $_FILES['pdffile'] on the back-end but it's not even set. Is this broken in version v2.7.18 of "api-platform/core"? When googling around I see it was either unsupported before or broken.

A multipart request needs the boundary value specified within the Content-Type header - but since you set the header yourself, the library is likely not overwriting it. Try and remove that header.

Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it's not the solution, still no file uploaded.
